# Wrong positioning of UIBarButtonItem

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I have this code for my UIBarButtonItem. When i'm trying with title, everything is ok, but with image it shows a little bit left then it should be. I don't know how to fix it, what can be wrong? Same problem if i do leftBarButtonItem.

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "123", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(toggleInterfaceStyle))

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "day"), style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(toggleInterfaceStyle))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the image have any transparency in it? Can you add the actual image itself to the question as well as the screen shots?

Answer (score 1):

1. This code could help you in terms of padding:

   ```
   let negativeSeperator = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil) 
   negativeSeperator.width = 12
   ```

Width must be positive in Swift version

2. Also you can use insets:

   ```
   barButtonItem.imageInsets = .init(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
   ```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, and there's a neat trick you can do with a UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace, add one of these with a negative width before your first button and after your last button and it will move the button to the edge

let negativeSeperator = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
negativeSeperator.width = 12

Comment: Exactly the same as the other answer (which preceded this one).